# Rails and mongoid: What is going on with RC7 and embedded documents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Until now I was using rc6 and I decided to upgrade, but it's totally 
breaking my app ? Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I believe I 
followed the documentation.

I have a model Content that embeds_many Localized_Content. 
Once I have a content created and wanted to added a localized content

I would do the following:

```
 @content = Content.find('xxx')
 @new_content = @content.localized_contants.build()
 @new_content.save
```

This is working perfectly fine under rc6 and updates correctly all the 
timestamps in localized_contant (using include Mongoid::Timestamps) 
But doing the same thing in rc7 break with the following error: 
"Access to the collection for LocalizedContent is not allowed since it 
is an embedded document, please access a collection from the root 
document."

Ok, maybe I need to save directly from the parent content then ok. 
Doing a

```
@content.save
```

works but will not trigger all the timestamping 
and this breaks the logic of my apps... what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

`@content.save` is the way to go. You should refactor your code to call `save()` on the parent object instead of the embedded document.